# CakePHP - Undefined variable in view when using $this->set("variableName', $variable) in controller;

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to set a variable in the view for my controller as so:

This is **Users/add** action

```
public function add() { 
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $usertype = $this->User->Usertypes->find('list', array('fields' => array('id', 'description')));
        $this->set('usertype', $usertype);
        $this->User->create();
        if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
}
```

When using Debugger::dump($usertype); I get this

```
array(  (int) 1 => 'Staff',     (int) 2 => 'Administrator',     (int) 3 => 'Coordinator' )
```

So $usertype is definitely set correctly. In my view found at /View/Users/add.ctp I attempt to access to variable like so:

This is **View/Users/add.ctp**

```
<div class="users form">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User'); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo __('Add User'); ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('firstName');
        echo $this->Form->input('lastName');
        echo $this->Form->input('email');
        echo $this->Form->input('password');
        echo $this->Form->input('usertypes_id',array('options'=>$usertype));
    ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
</div>
```

However I get an error "Undefined variable: usertype [APP/View/Users/add.ctp, line 10]"

I'm relatively new to CakePHP, I am doing something wrong here?

Comment: debug $usertype before this line in add.ctp

Comment: Also please mention the name of controller and action and its view file.

Comment: usertype is null prior to calling those two lines.
The controller is named UsersController, the action add() and the view add.ctp

Comment: You need to show your whole controller action, the full stack trace for the error is probably useful too. A variable being set _sometimes_ in a controller action doesn't mean it's set in the circumstance you're trying to use it in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to set your variable outside the `if` (before or after) otherwise the variable is set, bu then you are redirected to another page

Comment: Absolute legend, I knew it'd be something simple like this, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you are setting variable $usertype inside if, it means when request is POST but when you hit url request type is by default is GET.